# Como modificar la versión de compilación de android en VS xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Amigos estoy tratando de crear una aplicación en xamarin.forms en la cual tengo que implementar un BottomBarTabPage pero al momento de realizar la instalación por medio de NuGet me genera un error con respecto a la versión de compilación que en mi caso muestra que esta en la 24 y necesito mínimo la 26, ya la tengo instalada en el sdk pero no se como hacer para que el proyecto la reconozca, alguien me puede ayudar en solucionar el error.

Cabe resaltar que estoy trabajando en un proyecto cross-platform

Este es el error que me aparece.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que instalar el SDK que corresponde y los build tools desde el menú **Tools -> Android -> Android SDK Manager**.

Asegúrate de marcar el SDK correspondiente en la pestaña Platforms, a veces hay que instalar SDK más antiguos para que compilen librerías antiguas. No es necesario instalar las System Images, que pesan mucho y sirven para los emuladores.

En la pestaña Tools usa el **Android SDK Tools** más nuevo, instala el **Build Tools más nuevo** (puedes tener varios en simultáneo), y en la sección de Extras marca **Android Support Repository**, **Google Repository** y **Google Play Services**. Con eso debiera compilar correctamente.

Comment: todo los pasos que dices lo e echo ya desde un principio, el problema que tengo que siempre inicia en la version de compilacion 24 y necesito cambiar eso a la 26 minimo, pero no se como hacer lo,en la sdk build tools tengo instaladas las versiones 24.0.3,25.0.3,26.0.3,27,28.0.2 y el sdk tools tengo dos versiones instaladas una simple y otra version 25.2.25, ahora como puedo hacer paara que mi app compile en version 26???

Comment: En las propiedades del proyecto Android (click botón derecho en el proyecto, Properties) puedes elegir la versión del SDK (lengüeta Android Manifest, busca Target Api Version), o directamente desde el AndroidManifest.xml busca la línea
`<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="17" android:targetSdkVersion="27" />` y cambia el 27 por el número que desees.